A Chinese or an Asian movie about drunk-fighting to save captured women

The characters use alcohol to fight better
The girl loves the guy (I think Chinese,foreign), he teaches her how to fight while drunk
All of them fight like that
They saves some captured sex slaves 
They finds the guy girlfriend but the guy dies in the process
The girl and the girlfriend goes free 


drunk + fight + chinese => Jackie Chan.

@user58946 I posted a possible match, but you still can add any other details via the "edit" button, to avoid any downvotes or the question getting closed.

@ibrahimmahrir Normally I would agree but + sex slaves + guy dies = maybe not Jackie Chan.

You're describing Raging Phoenix starring JeeJa Yanin

A violent gang is abducting and killing women around Thailand. Sanim and his friends, having had loved ones abducted, have joined together to break the gang of kidnappers. In a botched kidnap attempt, Deu is saved by Sanim's crew. After learning their unique martial arts style, Deu helps lure the gang into an epic battle to save the women across Thailand.

It goes exactly like you described.




You are correct thanks

Glad I could help!
